# ErrorDocument 404 Not Sending Referrer Information: PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, referrer, errordocument

I'm using a standard htaccess ErrorDocument 404 to redirect users to a new page.  In order to customize the 404, I need to know their referrer information (from the page they Tried to visit).

$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is empty

I printed out all of my global variables and most contain the link to pageNotFound.php.

How can I retrieve this information? (Server-Side is preferred)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be in `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`  Yours is mispelled.

Comment: And so we get onto why you should always run a spell checker over your standards documents **before** submitting them...

Comment: Actually, technically the OP spelled referrer correctly. Sadly, the misspelling is in the HTTP spec.

Comment: Sorry typo on my part, but even so I'm left with null:

http://www.speedcountry.com/page/not_a_real_page.php (last one)

Comment: It works fine.  There I get ...HTTP_HOST : www.speedcountry.com
HTTP_REFERER : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760749/errordocument-404-not-sending-referrer-information-php/1760759
HTTP_USER_AGENT : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729) ...

Comment: @Asaph: It doesn't matter how it's spelled in English, the way that it is spelled in the spec is the correct way of spelling it (in this context).

Answer (score 1):

`HTTP_REFERER` doesn't have a double r. It's an unfortunate misspelling in the HTTP spec.